# Этимология слова айран

Tags: этимология

Какое происхождение у слова айран?

Заранее благодарствую

Comment: https://infourok.ru/issledovatelskaya-rabota-po-teme-ayran-eto-gordost-karachaya-3965616.html

Comment: @Sharon 50 видов кисломолочной продукции)

Comment: Приготовьте айран в домашних условиях, а нам пришлите видео.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этимология русского слова *айран* простая - заимствовано с Кавказа. От какого конкретно народа определить сложно, так как напиток распространённый.Разновидность айрана, кефир легенда связывает с карачаевским князем Бекмурзой Байчоровым, но само слово *айран* массово вошло в русский язык уже в наше время.

Если интересует более ранняя этимология, то Википедия пишет, -

> Пратюркский: *adïr- «отделять» + *-an «суффикс существительного» > *adïran «сыворотка» > *ayïran > ayran.

Comment: А что можно сказать о греческих корнях слова?  Например: Первые упоминания о "айране" относятся к периоду Древней Греции, где этот напиток был широко распространен. Греки называли его "ψωμοτύρι και γάλα" (psomotýri kai gála), что означает "хлеб и молоко". В ходе открытий и торговых связей айран распространился и стал популярным напитком в других странах Ближнего Востока, таких как Турция, Иран, Азербайджан. https://dzen.ru/a/ZSksZoacwUhXLACc  И еще: https://hayduk.livejournal.com/445627.html

Comment: @Sharon , что греки знали о существовании напитка. В русский язык слово попало не от них

Comment: А само слово греческое или тюркское? Кто у кого заимствовал?   А также сам напиток у кого появился сначала? Мне эта информация непонятна.

Comment: @Sharon слово тюркское, греки его, если верить вашему комментарию выше, называли напиток psomotýri kai gála. Да и методика производства больше подходит для кочевых народов

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, голос от меня.